# How to search data in SDSS according to SDSS object designation?

Tags: search, astronomy

I know how to use **ra**, **dec** and **objid** to search for the SDSS object.And I haven't found the function to search data in SDSS according to SDSS object designation.Like this: **SDSS J160517.76-010955.4**.
Now I just have some pictures which only have the SDSS object designation, so I want to know how to get more information about the SDSS object in SDSS website.Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should include your code in the question and tag the question with the programming language you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The object designation is formed from the RA and Dec. So you can break it down into the format you want.

There are many releases in SDSS, for DR7 image cutout, the information of your object can be found at:

http://cas.sdss.org/dr7/en/tools/explore/obj.asp?ra=16:05:17.76&dec=-01:09:55.4

Simbad search may be what you want?

http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-basic?Ident=SDSS+J160517.76-010955.4&submit=SIMBAD+search

Alternatively, you can try Vizier's Search by Position to get information from all the searchable catalogues:

http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-2